# backup copy of Oracle DB-server

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

Dears,
I manage an Oracle DB with multiple tables that contains hundreds of millions of records with limited retention time ( telco-CDRs ).
I plan to make a backup copy of the DB-server but I don't need to include the records in the backup.
this backup, will be useful in case the server crashes.
The data itself, is not important for me and I don't have enough space in our archive tape-library, all I need is to get the server up and running again ASAP.
Kindly share your experience.
thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't care about the data, you don't want a backup of the database.  It sounds like you just want to grab the table definitions from your source control system.  Or a logical export that excludes the data.

Comment: So exactly what _do_ you want to back up?  The OS?  The Oracle database installation ($ORACLE_HOME)?  The schema metadata?

Comment: @EdStevens:
if I backup:
- OS
_ The Oracle database installation ($ORACLE_HOME)
- The schema metadata
will this be enough to restore the server?
and how should I do this?
can RMON be helpful in this case ?

Comment: Will it be enough to restore the sever?  That depends on what you want to restore - what you imagine your worst-case scenario to be..  I find it incredible that you believe that you don't need to save the data itself.  That is a DBA's Prime Directive - "Don't lose the  data".  I can't advise on recovering the server itself. That partly depends on the nature of the loss. For saving the metadata, an oracle expdp with the CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY.

Comment: Thanks EdStevens --- It's clear for me that I don't need the data and won't bother losing it. Hence I do emphasize my need to lose the data ( I don't need it )... all I need is a good working and functional DB-server ..... the data for most recent one week will be reloaded from CSV files.